# How to optimize reusing a large std::unordered_map as a temporary in a frequently called function?

Tags: c++, memory, unordered-map

Simplified question with a working example: I want to reuse a std::unordered_map (let's call it umap) multiple times, similar to the following dummy code (which does not do anything meaningful). How can I make this code run faster?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <time.h>

unsigned size = 1000000;

void foo(){
    std::unordered_map<int, double> umap;
    umap.reserve(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // in my real program: umap gets filled with meaningful data here
        umap.emplace(i, i * 0.1);
    }
    // ... some code here which does something meaningful with umap
}

int main() {

    clock_t t = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        foo();
    }

    t = clock() - t;
    printf ("%f s\n",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

In my original code, I want to store matrix entries in umap. In each call to foo, the key values start from 0 up to N, and N can be different in each call to foo, but there is an upper limit of 10M for indices. Also, values can be different (contrary to the dummy code here which is always `i*0.1`).

I tried to make `umap` a non-local variable, for avoiding the repeated memory allocation of `umap.reserve()` in each call. This requires to call `umap.clear()` at the end of `foo`, but that turned out to be actually slower than using a local variable (I measured it).

Comment: Including a toy program that demonstrates the problem would be helpful here -- English descriptions are inherently more ambiguous than actual code samples.

Comment: What is the performance baseline (declaring a local map in foo)?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I just added a piece of code to clarify.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, version 1 in my "Edit".

Comment: In version 2, is `umap` being passed-by-reference when `foo(umap)` is called, or does each call make a copy of the map?

Comment: I asked about the performance figures. Also please prefer real buildable code over pseudocode.

Comment: I second that. Please extract a real [mcve], it's just to make sure that you first did your part trying to figure out what is wrong. With the snippets you gave, you didn't provide enough info to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It is passed by reference. I tried to explain a more clear question in Edit2.

Comment: @n.m. My first post was not clear enough. I restated the question in Edit2 with working code.

Comment: @Abaris In this example, `umap` always has same data set. Why do you recursively generate same data set again and again? Are these different with each other in your actual source code? The true solution is highly depending on it's details.

Comment: You're running into the problem that the standard specifies open hashing for std::unordered_map, when your use case would be much better served by closed hashing.  So you might try finding (or implementing) a closed hash map rather than using std::unordered_map

Comment: @Hiroki In my application, I store matrix entries in the map, and it can change in size and value in each call to foo(), but I know the maximum size of umap.

Comment: @Abaris thx :). One more questions. Is your key set of the `umap` always continuous integers `{ 1,2,3,4...,N }` and does the maximum value `N` changes through the recursion calls? Or does key set also change through the recursion calls like this `{1,2,3,4,...}` -> `{1,5,9,10,...}` -> ...?

Comment: @Hiroki thank you. It is always {0, 1, 2, ..., N} but N can change in each call. I added the response to your question in my post.

Comment: @ChrisDodd That's a good suggestion, I am reading about open/closed hashing to try to implement it myself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is any good way to accomplish what you're looking for directly -- i.e. you can't clear the map without clearing the map.  I suppose you could allocate a number of maps up-front, and just use each one of them a single time as a "disposable map", and then go on to use the next map during your next call, but I doubt this would give you any overall speedup, since at the end of it all you'd have to clear all of them at once, and in any case it would be very RAM-intensive and cache-unfriendly (in modern CPUs, RAM access is very often the performance bottleneck, and therefore minimizing the number cache misses is the way to maximize effiency).

My suggestion would be that if clear-speed is so critical, you may need to move away from using `unordered_map` entirely, and instead use something simpler like a `std::vector` -- in that case you can simply keep a number-of-valid-items-in-the-vector integer, and "clearing" the vector is a matter of just setting the count back to zero.  (Of course, that means you sacrifice `unordered_map`'s quick-lookup properties, but perhaps you don't need them at this stage of your computation?)

Comment: Thank for the suggestion Jeremy. One idea that I tried to speed up clear() was using the alternative to unordered_map, sparsepp, for which the clear() function was almost 4 times faster. Also, I have used the vector idea exactly the way you explained. For my application, for some cases, vector is faster and for some other unordered_map, depending on the size. I wanted to see if I can do something similar to a memory pool for unordered_map, but I think I can't.

Answer (score 2):

A simple and effective way is reusing same container and memory again and again with pass-by-reference as follows.
In this method, you can avoid their recursive memory allocation `std::unordered_map::reserve` and `std::unordered_map::~unordered_map` which both have the complexity O(num. of elemenrs):

```
void foo(std::unordered_map<int, double>& umap)
{        
    std::size_t N = ...// set N here

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        // overwrite umap[0], ..., umap[N-1]
        // If umap does not have key=i, then it is inserted.
        umap[i] = i*0.1;
    }

    // do something and not access to umap[N], ..., umap[size-1] !
}
```

The caller side would be as follows:

```
std::unordered_map<int,double> umap;
umap.reserve(size);

for(int i=0; i<50; ++i){
    foo(umap);
}
```

---

But since your key set is always continuous integers `{1,2,...,N}`, I think that `std::vector` which enables you to avoid hash calculations would be more preferable to save values `umap[0], ..., umap[N]`:

```
void foo(std::vector<double>& vec)
{    
    int N = ...// set N here

    for(int i = 0; i<N; ++i)
    {
        // overwrite vec[0], ..., vec[N-1]
        vec[i] = i*0.1;
    }

    // do something and not access to vec[N], ..., vec[size-1] !            
}
```

Comment: You wrote a very clean response, @Hiroki. I appreciate it. I have the vector version too and it works better than umap for smaller sizes, so I switch between them in my code, depending on the problem. I actually tried taking umap out of foo, the way you did, but I need to call umap.clear() at the end of foo (or it's beginning) for the next call and it made my code slower in total, because clear() is just slow I guess.

Comment: @Abaris many thx :) ! Why do you need to call `std::unordered_map::clear()` rather than overwriting the values of it? Do you have to erase or invalidate extra elements `(N, umap[N])`,..., `(size-1, umap[size-1])` for some reasons?

Comment: I mean the first N entries from the previous call. I had to mention this in my question, sorry about that. This is how I use umap to add entries in my original code: if there is an element with the same key, I will add their values, otherwise I'll add it as a new entry. If I don't clear umap from the previous call, is there any way I can reuse umap?

Comment: @Abaris Hmm… We may be failing to share the core of our problem :). Could you please show us a buildable toy source code which needs to call `std::unordered_map::clear()` ? I expect we can avoid it. For instance, [**This**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4YYxsj3KzdoDADCe) is my quick example of recursive calls without recursive allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to avoid all memory allocation by using a simple array? You've said above that you know the maximum size of `umap` over all calls to `foo()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <time.h>

constexpr int size = 1000000;
double af[size];

void foo(int N) {
    // assert(N<=size);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        af[i] = i;
    }
    // ... af
}

int main() {    
    clock_t t = clock();

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        foo(size /* or some other N<=size */);
    }

    t = clock() - t;
    printf ("%f s\n",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suggested in the comments, closed hashing would be better for your use case.  Here's a quick&dirty closed hash map with a fixed hashtable size you could experiment with:

```
template<class Key, class T, size_t size = 1000003, class Hash = std::hash<Key>>
class closed_hash_map {
    typedef std::pair<const Key, T>                     value_type;
    typedef typename std::vector<value_type>::iterator  iterator;
    std::array<int, size>                               hashtable;
    std::vector<value_type>                             data;
 public:
    iterator begin() { return data.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return data.end(); }
    iterator find(const Key &k) {
        size_t h = Hash()(k) % size;
        while (hashtable[h]) {
            if (data[hashtable[h]-1].first == k)
                return data.begin() + (hashtable[h] - 1);
            if (++h == size) h = 0; }
        return data.end(); }
    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& obj) {
        size_t h = Hash()(obj.first) % size;
        while (hashtable[h]) {
            if (data[hashtable[h]-1].first == obj.first)
                return std::make_pair(data.begin() + (hashtable[h] - 1), false);
            if (++h == size) h = 0; }
        data.emplace_back(obj);
        hashtable[h] = data.size();
        return std::make_pair(data.end() - 1, true); }
    void clear() {
        data.clear();
        hashtable.fill(0); }
};
```

It can be made more flexible by dynamically resizing the hashtable on demand when appropriate, and more efficient by using robin-hood replacment.